# Adding Icon for mac executable not working with pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I tried running this command `pyinstaller --onefile --console -i"ICON.icns" my_file.py`.
it did not do add the icon to the executable.
I am on a mac.
My file structure is like this:

```
Folder
|______ICON.icns
|
|______my_file.py
```

I ran the command `pyinstaller --onefile --console -i"ICON.icns" my_file.py` while in my working directory `folder`.

Comment: What does the generated spec file set the icon to?

Comment: It works on windows but it doesn't on a mac.